# Changing height viewport so it doesn't effect layout?

Tags: css, resize, height, responsive, viewport

Take these two websites for example.. twitter and amazon.

Notice when you change the height of the viewport nothing actually changes? Just the amount you can and can't see.

How is this achieved?

Comment: For many sites this is normal behavior. The height is determined by content and styling settings. The question seems odd. Elaborate if I misunderstood.

Comment: @Daniel change the height of your browser window and the layout doesn't change. Maybe its the way that I code which is why I'm getting responsive issues when I resize the viewport height.

Comment: Changing the height should not change any content in a normal regular website, unless it is specifically designed to do so. Changing the width of a site, may change the height of the site (or actually the document), when text gets compressed and elements are wrapping to the next line. This of course can be controlled in the styling. If you set elements up that are relative to the view height css `vh` it may cause some of this issues. That is what I can come up with it my imagination.  If you need more info, show some specific code.